# How to organize variables into dataframe but not populate value of variables per column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in variables that I want to add into a dataframe. The issue I am running into is that I need to organize the variables where they are not populating every row.

I need the data to look like this:

```
 name   notification1   notification2   notification3
    a          1        
    b                          2    
    c                                         3
```

The dataframe currently look like this:

```
name    notification1   notification2   notification3
a          1                1             1 
b          2                2             2
c          3                3             3
```

The variables are set up like(all variables are str):

```
notification1 = 1.0
notification2 = 2.0
notification3 = 3.0
person_notification1 = a
person_notification2 = b
person_notification3 = c
```

Every notification has only one person attached to it, so not every row needs data per person.

Thank you in advance hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Where's the code you are using to create this dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

notification1 = 1.0
notification2 = 2.0
notification3 = 3.0
person_notification1 = 'a'
person_notification2 = 'b'
person_notification3 = 'c'

def row(name, notification):
    return {'name': name, 'notification_'+str(notification) : notification}

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(row(person_notification1, int(notification1)),ignore_index=True)
df = df.append(row(person_notification2, int(notification2)),ignore_index=True)
df = df.append(row(person_notification3, int(notification3)),ignore_index=True)
```

The result:

```
  name  notification_1  notification_2  notification_3
0    a             1.0             NaN             NaN
1    b             NaN             2.0             NaN
2    c             NaN             NaN             3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing your data in lists, instead of individual variables.

```
notifs = [1, 2, 3]
persons = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Initialise a diagonal 2D array using `np.diag`, and pass it to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(
     np.diag(notifs), 
     index=persons, 
     columns=np.arange(1, len(notifs) + 1)
).add_prefix('notification')

   notification1  notification2  notification3
a              1              0              0
b              0              2              0
c              0              0              3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want each column having only one value and rest as empty string. Please find the my solution below. I hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    notification = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
    persons = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    columns  = ['notification{}'.format(i) for i, elem in enumerate(notification, 1)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for r,c,v in zip(persons,columns,notification):
        df.at[r,c] = v

    df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
    print(df)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
  notification1 notification2 notification3
a             1                            
b                           2              
c                                         3
```